# TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW does not commit before JMS consume

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I am making some calculations and trying to save their results to database.When server finishes its job,
I am sending A JMS message to client to indicate that results are computed, then user can view it.But my problem when user clicks results, he/She does not see anything.Because results are not in the database.When he presses second time, then the results are there. Approxiamtely, after 1/2 seconds of comsuming JMS message, the results are saved to database.

To solve problem I am creating bean A, that calls method of B bean. The method of B bean, makes calculations and saves database. I defined TRansactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW in method of B.
After invocation of mehod of B ends, I am sending JMS message to client.But the transaction is not committed at that time.

```
@Stateless
public class A implements ARemote
 public void methodA()
{
   // call method of B
   // Send JMS message
}
@Singleton
public class B implements BRemote
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void methodB()
{
}
```

Comment: how do you call methodB()?

Comment: With injection@EJB
B bBean;